# Use timeline keyframes with JavaFX within a for loop

Tags: java, javafx

How would I create a timeline keyframe so that it adds each addition of the chart to a new key frame, so that they appear one at a time?

```
  Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
  ArrayList<XYChart.Series> lineSeries2 = new ArrayList<XYChart.Series>();
  for (int s = 0; s<(pointCount); s++) {
    XYChart.Series b = new XYChart.Series();
    b.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Double, Double>(xVal[s], yVal[s] ));
    lineChart.getData().add(b);
  }
```

Comment: Instead of creating seperate `KeyFrame`s, you could use a single one and adjust the cycle count. The event handler used with this `KeyFrame` could e.g. use an `Iterator`...

Answer (score 0):

The Timeline needs a KeyFrame, as you mentioned, so let's add one.

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
timeline.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), e -> {
    //add one data point here   
}));

timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
timeline.playFromStart();
```

With this code, the eventhandler of the KeyFrame gets called once a second, so you can add a new data point everytime you reach that point. There is no need for a `for` loop.